# AudioQueue get a wrong numbers of Packet?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audioqueue

My app  uses **ffmpeg to  parse mms streaming** to buffers, and uses **Audio queue** to play the buffered data. Now I can confirm the buffered data is good, but I can not play it. The structure of playing is based on the AudioFileStreamExample demo's client, and it can play the ***http stream(AudioFileStreamExample demo's server)***. I notice in the callback  function:

```
void MyPacketsProc(void *inClientData, UInt32 inNumberBytes, 
    UInt32 inNumberPackets, const void *inInputData, 
    AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescriptions),
```

When I directly play the AudioFileStreamExample demo's http stream, the param `inNumberPackets` is bigger than 1 at most times; when I play the mms stream, the `inNumberPackets` is always 1. audioQueue only play the first packet, all of the last packets are missed.

The log of using AudioFileStreamExample demo's http stream:

```
*AudioStreamBasicDescription info ----*

SampleRate        :44100.000000
FormatID          :778924083
FormatFlags       :0
BytesPerPacket    :0
FramesPerPacket   :1152
BytesPerFrame     :0
ChannelsPerFrame  :2
BitsPerChannel    :0

got data.  bytes: 1253  packets: 2
packetSize:626   
kAQBufSize:24576

bytesFilled:0
packetSize:627   


kAQBufSize:24576
bytesFilled:626

got data.  bytes: 627  packets: 1
packetSize:627   

kAQBufSize:24576

bytesFilled:1253
```

The log of using  parsed mms stream:

```
*AudioStreamBasicDescription info ----*

SampleRate        :48000.000000
FormatID          :1819304813
FormatFlags       :12
BytesPerPacket    :4
FramesPerPacket   :1
BytesPerFrame     :4
ChannelsPerFrame  :2
BitsPerChannel    :16

got data.  bytes: 4498  packets: 1


packetSize:216      
kAQBufSize:24576    
bytesFilled:0    

got data.  bytes: 1090  packets: 1


packetSize:576       
kAQBufSize:24576    
bytesFilled:216

got data.  bytes: 3064  packets: 1


packetSize:576     
kAQBufSize:24576    
bytesFilled:792

got data.  bytes: 3978  packets: 1


packetSize:252       
kAQBufSize:24576    
bytesFilled:1368
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. It seems that `MyPacketsProc` function gets wrong params, but how to get fix it?

thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happens with me also, 
it seems it happens when AudioQueue callback doesn't invoke on the time.